# Как сделать опрос в Telegram Bot PHP? Шаги (step)

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет!

Подскажите пожалуйста, **как сделать опрос в Telegram Bot PHP?**
Не голосование, а опрос. Шаги! (step)

Т.е. цепочка вопросов пользователю и ответы пользователя текстом и/или кнопками (типо Да или Нет)

Использую эту библиотеку https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Спасибо!

Comment: Вам на webhook приходят запросы, в виде сообщений от telegram или же вы сами его опрашиваете, это по усмотрению. Далее, вы должен уметь понимать, что за позиция у принятого сообщения в списке и отправлять в тот же чат следующее. Т.е., вы же есть сервер и должны держать у себя полную цепочку сообщений опроса, уметь его откатывать и отдавать следующее сообщение относительно текущего.

Comment: Если комментария выше недостаточно, в таком случае опиши, что вы уже пытались сделать, что произошло, возможно какие-то ошибки?

Comment: Да, я делал указав в users поле step и туда пишу шаги. Но возможно есть более оптимальное решение!?

Comment: Это даже вполне нормальный вариант, если вы в таблицу пользователей пишите каждому юзеру последний его шаг, под это в более каноничной реализации можно было создать промежуточную таблицу вроде `user_step` и писать в нее внешние ключи, соответственно id юзера и id шага, возможно timestamp ответа на последний шаг, если бы вы хотели еще как-то примешать логику обработки по времени. Вроде, если ответ был дан слишком давно.